# Print tic tac toe board fortran90

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90, tic-tac-toe

I am just trying to create a subroutine to print out the current state of the board in tic tac toe. Zeros are blank spaces, 1's are X's, and 2's are O's. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code, but ti would print out the current state, instead it prints out a bunch of different, incorrect boards. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

!!!!!!!!!This is my code and subroutine:

```
program ttt
implicit none
integer, dimension(9) :: board
integer :: playerx
character (len=1), dimension(9) :: cboard
integer :: i, j

!Print board with numbered spots

 !print *, "Enter a number 1-9 to play tic-tac-toe"
 print *, " "
 print "(a11)", " 1 | 2 | 3 "
 print "(a11)", "---+---+---"
 print "(a11)", " 4 | 5 | 6 "
 print "(a11)", "---+---+---"
 print "(a11)", " 7 | 8 | 9 "
 print *, " "

  board = (/ 2, 0, 0, &
             0, 1, 0, &
             0, 0, 1 /)
  playerx = 1

call printboard(board, playerx)
 
end program ttt

! Subroutine to print out the current state of the board
subroutine printboard(board, playerx)
implicit none
integer, intent(in), dimension(9) :: board
integer, intent(in) :: playerx
character (len=1), dimension(9) :: cboard
integer :: i, j

! board array is series of 1s, 2s, and 0s. set 1 = x, 2 = o, and 0 = " "
if (playerx == 1) then
do i = 1,9

   do j = 1, 9
    if (board(i) == 0) cboard(j) = " "
    if (board(i) == 1) cboard(j) = "x"
    if (board(i) == 2) cboard(j) = "o"
 
if (j < 0 .and. j < 4) then
  print "(a1, a1, a3, a1, a3, a1)", " ", cboard(j), " | ", cboard(j), " | ", cboard (j)
  print "(a11)", "---+---+---"

  endif
if (j > 3 .and. j < 7) then
  print "(a1, a1, a3, a1, a3, a1)", " ", cboard(j), " | ", cboard(j), " | ", cboard (j)
  print "(a11)", "---+---+---"
  endif
if (j > 6 .and. j < 10) then
  print "(a1, a1, a3, a1, a3, a1)", " ", cboard(j), " | ", cboard(j), " | ", cboard (j)
  print "(a11)", " "
  endif
endif

end subroutine printboard
```

This is what the code produces:

```
 1 | 2 | 3 
---+---+---
 4 | 5 | 6 
---+---+---
 7 | 8 | 9 
  
 o | o | o
---+---+---
 o | o | o
---+---+---
 o | o | o
---+---+---
 o | o | o
           
 o | o | o
           
 o | o | o
           
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
 x | x | x
---+---+---
 x | x | x
---+---+---
 x | x | x
---+---+---
 x | x | x
           
 x | x | x
           
 x | x | x
           
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
---+---+---
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
   |   |  
           
 x | x | x
---+---+---
 x | x | x
---+---+---
 x | x | x
---+---+---
 x | x | x
           
 x | x | x
           
 x | x | x
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour]. What is the expected output? What is wrong on the current output?

Comment: Think carefully about what is happening in that loop with `j` and its interaction with the outer `i` loop.

Comment: I would like to help, but it looks like a homework problem... what is print, ("all")?

Comment: @Holmz, is your typeface not showing the edit descriptor as `a11` instead of `all`?

Comment: Thanks @francescalus, it was an iPad on the bus yesterday, so maybe the ride was too bouncy.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be a little bit complicated. I would have it simplified here and there.

First of all, you can use `2D` array to store your data. I think it would be way more natural.

Instead of filling `character(1), dimension(3,3) :: cboard` based on values from `integer, dimension(3,3) :: board` you can simply introduce function that will provide required `character` depending on the value stored inside your `board`.

When it comes to printing, I think that putting multiple `print` sections, that behave differently (depending on whether there will be a new line or not), is an overkill.

It is also a good idea to put parts of the code (that are responsible for a certain logic of your application) into modules. This way, you can reuse and replace them. E.g. you can easily add new module that will print your board differently.

When it comes to `Fortran`, it's a good idea to remember column/row order in arrays. Might be confusing for people coming with the experience based on different languages.

```
module board_printer

implicit none

contains

  function integer2char(x)

    integer, intent(in) :: x
    character(1)        :: integer2char

    if(x == 0)      then integer2char = ' '
    else if(x == 1) then integer2char = 'x'
    else                 integer2char = 'o'
    end if

  end function integer2char

  subroutine printboard(board)

    integer, intent(in), dimension(3, 3) :: board
    integer                              :: i

    do i = 1, 3
      write(*, fmt="(a)") ' '//integer2char(board(i,1))//' | '//integer2char(board(i,2))//' | '//integer2char(board(i,3))//' '
      if( i /= 3) then
        write(*, fmt="(a)") '---+---+---'
      end if
    end do
    write(*,*) ""

  end subroutine printboard

end module board_printer

program ttt

use board_printer
implicit none

  integer, dimension(3, 3) :: board

  write(*,fmt="(a)") "Enter a number 1-9 to play tic-tac-toe"
  write(*,fmt="(a)") " "
  write(*,fmt="(a)") ' 1 | 4 | 7 '
  write(*,fmt="(a)") '---+---+---'
  write(*,fmt="(a)") ' 2 | 5 | 8 '
  write(*,fmt="(a)") '---+---+---'
  write(*,fmt="(a)") ' 3 | 6 | 9 '
  write(*,fmt="(a)") ''

  board = reshape((/ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 /), shape(board) )
  call printboard(board)

  board = reshape((/ 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 /), shape(board) )
  call printboard(board)

  board = reshape((/ 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 /), shape(board) )
  call printboard(board)

  board = reshape((/ 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2 /), shape(board) )
  call printboard(board)

  board = reshape((/ 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1 /), shape(board) )
  call printboard(board)

end program ttt
```